# Remove Duplicate value from report mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to run a query that outputs a report for a given period (i.e. a month) and to display all fees charged to a customer and the amount paid (if any). My problem is that is displaying the amount paid on every row for that customer. I want to show all charges and one payment amount (let's say at the last row). Do not display duplicates paid amount for a customer

```
Last NameFirst NameMIDate of ServiceFeePayment
 BarrazaReyD5/1/2013$160.00 $0.00 
 BarrazaReyD5/1/2013$12.10 $0.00 
 OteroAliciaM5/3/2013$84.68 $329.20 
 OteroAliciaM5/3/2013$99.46 $329.20 
 OteroAliciaM5/3/2013$46.59 $329.20 
 OteroAliciaM5/3/2013$48.98 $329.20 
 OteroAliciaM5/3/2013$26.35 $329.20 
 OteroAliciaM5/3/2013$23.14 $329.20 
 Mayweather Bethy 5/5/2013$99.46 $249.70 
 Mayweather Bethy 5/5/2013$97.96 $249.70 
 Mayweather Bethy 5/6/2013$34.73 $249.70 
 Mayweather Bethy 5/6/2013$17.55 $249.70 
 GarciaMichael 5/11/2013$198.92 $0.00 
 GarciaMichael 5/11/2013$29.95 $0.00 
 GarciaMichael 5/11/2013$17.30 $0.00 
 SmithRichard 5/15/2013$35.00 $0.00 
 SmithRichard 5/15/2013$2.64 $0.00 
 BoothKeithR5/23/2013$14.64 $0.00 
 BoothKeithR5/23/2013$255.30 $0.00 
 BoothKeithR5/23/2013$66.99 $0.00 
 SmithVanessa 5/23/2013$18.00 $0.00 
 SmithVanessa 5/23/2013$1.36 $0.00 
 HERNANDEZLAURA 5/25/2013$34.47 $0.00 
 MyersJonathan 5/30/2013$35.00 $37.65 
 MyersJonathan 5/30/2013$2.65 $37.65
```

It is displaying the total amount paid for every fee charged to a customer. My query is this

```
$query = "SELECT
 c.lname as lname,
 c.fname as fname,
 c.mname as mname,
 s.date as date,
 b.fee as fee,
 p.amount as payment,
 FROM sell as s,
 customer as c,
 billing b
 LEFT JOIN payments p on p.completion = b.completion AND p.cid=b.cid
 WHERE      
 s.completion = b.completion
 AND b.cid = s.cid
 AND c.pid = s.cid
 AND s.date BETWEEN ? and ?
 ORDER BY s.date";
```

I tried `GROUP BY p.amount` but leaves only one row for that customer and cuts all other fees. I need to display all fees charged to customer but only **one** amount as payment. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing join styles (ANSI joins and comma joins) in your query. Don't do that. Try always use ANSI JOIN notation. It's more descriptive.

That being said I believe your query should look like

```sql
SELECT c.lname,
       c.fname,
       c.mname,
       s.date,
       b.fee,
       p.amount payment
  FROM sell s JOIN customer c
    ON s.cid = c.pid JOIN billing b
    ON s.cid = b.cid 
   AND s.completion = b.completion LEFT JOIN payments p 
    ON b.completion = p.completion 
   AND b.cid = p.cid
 WHERE s.date BETWEEN ? AND ?
 ORDER BY s.date
```

*The query obviously has not been tested*

If that doesn't solve your problem you have to edit your question and post relevant sample data for all your tables involved (a few rows) just to to produce desired output (which you've already posted) in the same tabular form.

Comment: This doesn't fetch the payment total for a given customer, does it?

Comment: @LexLythius OP didn't ask explicitly for totals in his question. And OP's desired output confirms that.

Comment: Well, I think we need clarification. I understand he does need to total payment. "I need all the information but only one payment" is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: The question might need some clarification. But probably it's more reasonable to ask OP for it, don't you think?

Comment: Clarification: For a given period (say a month) you run a report where displays all customers that got charged for that month (one row per charge) and any payment  made. What the query is doing is that the payment (from payments table - where you get the total amount paid) is displaying it every row where there is a charge. The amount is correct but I only need "one" payment in one row per customer (let's say the end) not in every row. I do not know how to display only one value per customer instead of every charge. I do need however every charge broken down

Comment: @user2031297 Great. Thanks. That's what I thought. Now to help you with that intelligently please edit your question and post table structures and sample data.

Comment: @user2031297 If you want to be helped, again, post table structures and sample data for every table (sell, customer, billing, payment) **separately**, not the result of your current query as you currently did

Answer (score 0):

To get the details of every charge for given customers, @peterm solution should work.

You will still be lacking the total payments made by each customer. For that, you need to do a separate query:

```
SELECT c.cid,
       SUM(p.amount) AS payment_total
  FROM sell s JOIN customer c
  ... all necessary joins here
  GROUP BY c.cid
```